# UITableViewCell - Multiple Cell Identifiers showing viewWithTag = nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a prototype cell created in storyboard with all the tags working/displaying correctly. I wanted to create a duplicate prototype cell but change some of the visual elements, so that I can display both the original and new prototype cell in one table. I copied my old prototype cell in storyboard, giving it a new identifier, and redesigned it to look like the new cell. However, in my new cell, one of the views is being initialized as nil (subView). I really can't figure out why this is the case since this view loads up correctly in the old prototype cell, yet it just won't initialize in the new cell (even though it has the same exact viewWithTag number). From all the reading I've been doing, I believe it has to do with the whole cell reuse idea, but I can't pinpoint the problem...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  static NSString *AnnouncementCellIdentifier = @"AnnouncementCell";
  static NSString *EventCellIdentifier = @"EventCell";
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TBD";


  if(self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
    GenericPost *announcement = [self.announcements objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    if ([announcement isMemberOfClass: [Event class]]){
      CellIdentifier = EventCellIdentifier;
    }
    else {
      CellIdentifier = AnnouncementCellIdentifier;
    }
  }


  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
  NSLog(@"CellIdentifier: %@",CellIdentifier);
  if (!cell) { // THIS IS NEVER CALLED JUST AS AN FYI
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }


 UIView *contentView = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag: 0];
  UIView *subView = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:0];


  if(self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
    GenericPost *announcement = [self.announcements objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    contentView = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag: 100];
    subView = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:101]; // THIS LINE RIGHT HERE SHOWS MY SUBVIEW IS INITIALIZED TO NIL WHEN CELLIDENTIFIER = EventCell, yet it works fine for AnnouncementCell
```

Printout:

```
2014-03-03 19:17:47.480 MyApp[23213:70b] CellIdentifier: EventCell
2014-03-03 19:17:47.481 MyApp[23213:70b] view is a UITableViewCell with tag = 0
2014-03-03 19:17:47.481 MyApp[23213:70b]     view is a UITableViewCellScrollView with tag = 0
2014-03-03 19:17:47.482 MyApp[23213:70b]         view is a UITableViewCellContentView with tag = 100
2014-03-03 19:17:47.482 MyApp[23213:70b]             view is a UIView with tag = 106
2014-03-03 19:17:47.482 MyApp[23213:70b]                 view is a UISegmentedControl with tag = 107
2014-03-03 19:17:47.482 MyApp[23213:70b]                     view is a UISegment with tag = 0
2014-03-03 19:17:47.483 MyApp[23213:70b]                         view is a UISegmentLabel with tag = 0
2014-03-03 19:17:47.483 MyApp[23213:70b]                         view is a UIImageView with tag = -1030
2014-03-03 19:17:47.483 MyApp[23213:70b]                     view is a UISegment with tag = 0
2014-03-03 19:17:47.484 MyApp[23213:70b]                         view is a UISegmentLabel with tag = 0
2014-03-03 19:17:47.484 MyApp[23213:70b]                         view is a UIImageView with tag = -1030
2014-03-03 19:17:47.484 MyApp[23213:70b]                     view is a UISegment with tag = 0
2014-03-03 19:17:47.485 MyApp[23213:70b]                         view is a UISegmentLabel with tag = 0
2014-03-03 19:17:47.485 MyApp[23213:70b]                         view is a UIImageView with tag = -1030
2014-03-03 19:17:47.485 MyApp[23213:70b]             view is a UIView with tag = 999
2014-03-03 19:17:47.486 MyApp[23213:70b]                 view is a UILabel with tag = 0
2014-03-03 19:17:47.486 MyApp[23213:70b]                 view is a UILabel with tag = 0
2014-03-03 19:17:47.486 MyApp[23213:70b]                 view is a UILabel with tag = 0
2014-03-03 19:17:47.487 MyApp[23213:70b]                 view is a UILabel with tag = 0
2014-03-03 19:17:47.487 MyApp[23213:70b]                 view is a UILabel with tag = 0
2014-03-03 19:17:47.487 MyApp[23213:70b]                 view is a UIScrollView with tag = 103
2014-03-03 19:17:47.487 MyApp[23213:70b]                     view is a UITextView with tag = 104
2014-03-03 19:17:47.488 MyApp[23213:70b]                         view is a _UITextContainerView with tag = 0
2014-03-03 19:17:47.488 MyApp[23213:70b]                             view is a UITextSelectionView with tag = 0
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `UIView *subview = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:0];`?

Comment: Also the `if (!cell)` doesn't get called because that's the old way to do it. In iOS 6 they added the method you're using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` that automatically creates the cell if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Are you certain that both prototype cells have a subview with tag==101?  Searching for tag==0 often generates unexpected results, if the programmer forgets that the receiver (in addition to it's subviews) can be found.  i.e. if the cell's tag is zero, you'll get subview assigned to be the cell, not any subview.

Comment: @Can I've tried doing it cell.contentView and it didn't make a difference

Comment: @danh Yes, both prototype cells have a subview with tag == 101. The second cell was a copy paste from the first one and the Attribute Inspector verifies this is the case. The thing to note is that I also have other tags in my second prototype cell that were in my first cell, but they ARE initialized correctly. For some reason, it's just my subView...I've tried assigning it a different tag number and still no luck.

Comment: What is interesting to note is if I drag a new UIView into my subView (positioned to take up 1/4 of the space of my subView) and then assign it a tag, in my cellForRowAtIndexPath, I can change the background color and it works, but it changes the background color for all of my subview, not just the 1/4 space I set it to occupy in StoryBoard

Comment: Try use `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:]` without `forIndexPath` addiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see what your view hierarchy really looks like, please add the following:

```
- (void)logTags:(UIView *)view indent:(NSInteger)indent {

    NSLog(@"%*sview is a %@ with tag = %d", indent, "", view.class, view.tag);

    for (UIView *subview in [view subviews]) {
        [self logTags:subview indent:indent+4];
    }
}
```

then, after dequeueing a cell, log that cell.  (pick a single row to limit the amount of output)

```
UITableViewCell *cell = // ....

if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    [self logTags:cell indent:0];
}
```

Comment: Very interesting! So it took a bit to realize I needed to add the quotes to get the function to work

, indent, "", view.class, view.tag 

But the interesting thing is that my subView exists, but it has tag = 999! I changed my viewWithTag to be = 999 and everything works, but I'm not sure how do I get it working correctly with the Tag number I want to assign? I searched my code and nowhere do I programmatically assign my subView tag to 999 and in storyboard it's clearly listed as equal to 101. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, my bad on the spaces.  Will edit.  On the mysterious 999, the only way I can think of is via code.  You searched code for "999"?  Maybe you're doing math somewhere?  view.tag = 1000-1;  ??

Comment: Still wasn't able to figure out where the 999 came from, but I'll keep looking. Thanks for the help!

Comment: edit: omg i'm so stupid...i copy/pasted my view controller and was editing the wrong view controller the whole time...wow